# Inconsistency - Removing rows from a dataframe only partially works

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am going crazy over an inconsistency using pandas.

I am using a set of timeseries read from csvs into dataframes. Each dataframe has a DateTime index and I assign the dataframes to a list such that I can use in loops etc:

```
timeseries_list = [yval, yhat_lstm, yhat_linreg, yhat_gbm, yhat_cnn, yhat_phys]
timeseries_name = ['yval', 'yhat_lstm', 'yhat_linreg', 'yhat_gbm', 'yhat_cnn', 'yhat_phys']
```

I then did some data processing and cleaning in which which I removed the first row of yhat_lstm, such that it matches the shape of all other dataframes:

```
yhat_lstm = yhat_lstm.iloc[1:]

[in] yhat_lstm.shape
[out] (3341, 24)
```

Here is the problem: when I am looping through the timeseries_list, the *yhat_lstm* seems to have it's original shape for some reason i.e. (3342,24). That's giving me huge problems.

Example:

```
[in]     for i,v in enumerate(timeseries_list):
             print (i, timeseries_name[i], v['0'].size)

[out]     0 yval 3341
          1 yhat_lstm 3342
          2 yhat_linreg 3341
          3 yhat_gbm 3341
          4 yhat_cnn 3341
          5 yhat_phys 3341
```

However:

```
[in]     yhat_lstm['0'].size

[out]    3341
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `yhat_lstm` in your list and the global `yhat_lstm` referencing the same dataframe? When you do your data processing, did you do something like `yhat_lstm=...`? In other words, your data processing might not all be `in place`. That way the `yhat_lstm` in your list is no longer the same as `yhat_lstm` in global scope.

You can check by `print(yhat_lstm is timeseries_list[1])`; if `yhat_lstm` is mutated, it would give you `False`.

Comment: You are right it returns False. The processing was to remove the first row via `yhat_lstm = yhat_lstm.iloc[1:]` and divide by 1000 via `yhat_lstm = yhat_lstm.divide(1000)`. I thought assigning to itself implies inplace? I haven't gotten across this issue before

Comment: @KPr A lot of times, default behavior of pandas is actually not inplace but return a new dataframe. In operations that support `inplace`, you can pass `inplace=True`. But seems like `df.divide` doesn't support `inplace`. So you have to reassign the dataframe back to the list.